# How change an attribute value using Xpath and the fn:replace function?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Is possible change the values of all the attributes called `Entry` to a new value at once using the XPath replace function? or I must iterate over all the nodes manually and replace each attribute value myself?

I had this Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Root>
  <Items>
    <action type="xta">
      <Menu Type="2"  Entry="Foo1"  />
      <Menu Type="1"  Entry="Foo2"/>
      <Menu Type="1"  Entry="Foo3"/>
      <Menu Type="1"  Entry="Foo4"/>
    </action>
  </Items>
</Root>
```

I want get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Root>
  <Items>
    <action type="xta">
      <Menu Type="2"  Entry="Bar\Foo1"  />
      <Menu Type="1"  Entry="Bar\Foo2"/>
      <Menu Type="1"  Entry="Bar\Foo3"/>
      <Menu Type="1"  Entry="Bar\Foo4"/>
    </action>
  </Items>
</Root>
```

If not is possible using XPath directly, which is the best way to acomplish this using c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is not a straight XPath navigation operation, it is a transform. There are multiple ways to accomplish changing the Xml, but your two best are probably these:

1. You can use the [XslCompiledTransform Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) with an xslt. (Also see [Using the XslCompiledTransform Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0610k0w4.aspx))
2. You can use the [XDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) in [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and change it via C# code.